# Create a special character in a .txt file using C#

Tags: c#, console

I have to render a special character in a string while creating a .txt file. The Code for the special character is **"\x0B"**. But we I try to concat it in a string its giving me text as it is. Can you tell how to render the special character using the above code?

```
 String totalText = totalText + @"\x0B"+ @"Text seperated with the character";
 File.WriteAllText(path + createFileName + ".txt", totalText);
```

Comment: Help us help you - share your code

Comment: Done, added the code used

Comment: `char c = '\x0B';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a [verbatim string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) by preceding your string with an '@'. This means that nothing gets escaped, except for double quotes using `""`, which resolves to `"`.

Does this work?

```
String totalText = totalText + "\x0B"+ @"Text seperated with the character";
File.WriteAllText(path + createFileName + ".txt", totalText);
```

Comment: `"\x0B"` should be `'\x0B'`

Comment: `string totalText = totalText + ...` should fail because you use a unassigned local variable. Even if it would compile it wouldn't make sense sice there is no value in it.

Comment: @fubo: In string concatenation there's no real point to make one operand a `char` when it can be a `string` just as well. The snippet is also taken from the question and the asker most likely has more code around that snippet that's not important for the question.

Comment: @Joey Isn't OP failed to provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Joey _the special character is "\x0B"_ - there is a mistake in the question - in case of a string these are 4 characters

Comment: @fubo: »The **code** for the special character is ...« (emphasis mine). Honestly, that's perfectly clear and understandable to anyone who has been using a C-like programming language for a while. Yes, there are four characters in the source code. No, that doesn't mean that those four characters should be written to the file. Are you complaining that `\n` is two characters in source code, but just one in memory as well?

Comment: I had other suggestions as well, but provided the minimum amount of change needed for the code to work.

Answer (score 1):

Remove unnecessary verbatim string literals, use `Path.Combine`:

```
string totalText = "Some text";
char c = '\x0B';
string textSeparatedWithCharacter = "Text seperated with the character";

totalText = $"{totalText}{c}{textSeparatedWithCharacter}";

// Or
//totalText = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", totalText, c, textSeparatedWithCharacter);

File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(path, createFileName + ".txt"), totalText);
```